# Matching CRTP in template class

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

lately I've been toying around with templates and stumbled upon the following problem. I am implementing the CRTP pattern like this:

```
template<typename derived_t>
struct protocol_object
{
    ...
};

struct data_object : public protocol_object<data_object>
{
    ...
};
```

I now would like to match instances of `class protocol_object` in a member template function, while still accepting non CRTP-types:

```
struct consumer_impl
{
    template<typename derived_t>
    void match(protocol_object<derived_t> &value)
    {
       std::cout << "protocol_class";
    };

    template<typename T>
    void match(T &value)
    {
       std::cout << "any other type";
    };
}
```

Unfortunately only the second version is ever called. Apparently `match(protocol_object<derived_t> &value)` is not considered or rejected in favour of the more general form `match(T &value)`.

```
data_object object;
double value;
consumer_impl consumer;

consumer.match(value);  // yields "any other type" OK
consumer.match(object); // also yields "any other type" but want "protocol_class"
```

Is there a way out of this?

Thanks for any hints.
Arne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't related to CRTP.  It's a general case of the following:

- Design a template function, such that all derived classes use a particular specialization.

The issue is that `T& value` is an exact match for `Derived&`, while `Base&` is an inexact match.  So we shall make the general form a worse match:

```
struct conversion_required { conversion_required(int) {} };

template<typename derived_t>
void match_impl(protocol_object<derived_t> &value, int)
{
   std::cout << "protocol_class";
};

template<typename T>
void match_impl(T &value, conversion_required)
{
   std::cout << "any other type";
};

template<typename T>
void match(T& value)
{
    return match_impl(value, 0);
}
```

Now the specialization, requiring an upcast, is a better match than the general template, requiring a user-defined conversion.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that tomorrow. I was thinking in the same line, but was hoping that there was a solution that didn't require a line similar to `conversion_required(int) {}` for each "general" type.

Comment: @Arne: The same `conversion_required` class can be used as often as you like.  You could even use `const char*` and `std::string` for the purpose.

Comment: This solution doesn't reliably work for me.  http://pastebin.com/RHPqX6uC  To summarize, gcc 4.8.0 compiles but warns: "ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second: [enabled by default]", and clang tip-ish errors: "call to 'match_impl' is ambiguous".  Pastebin link includes the exact source I'm compiling.  Any chance you could post a working solution?  (I'm attempting a fix, but I'm weak on C++ overload semantics and might not divine the solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Overload resolution is performed based on the *static type*, since it is a compile-time compiler decision. Try this:

```
consumer.match(static_cast<protocol_object<data_object>&>(object));
```

Answer (score 0):

The second function is a better match, as no conversion is required for it, whereas the first function requires a derived-to-base conversion.

You can use boost to overcome this:

```
template <class T>
void
match (typename boost::enable_if_c
             <boost::is_base_of<protocol_object<T>,T>::value, T>::type& t)
{
    std::cout << "protocol_class";
}

template <class T>
void
match (typename boost::disable_if_c
             <boost::is_base_of<protocol_object<T>,T>::value, T>::type& t)
{
    std::cout << "any other type";
}
```

This will work for all classes `T` derived from `protocol_object<T>`, but not for `protocol_object<T>` itself. You can add another overload for it (basically, reuse your first `match` function), or modify the condition in `enable_if` so that it matches `protocol_object<T>` too.